# Web scraping with java script and log in in python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, dryscrape

I'm trying to scrape a website where a log-in is needed and a java Script is running.

I'm able to log in using HTMLSession from requests_html. But the problem is, I didn't find a way to execute the java script. So I tried using dryscrape which works fine for the Java srcipt except session.post() is not working for the dryscrape module, so I can't log in.

So next step is I need a general idea on how to combine either those two session, or a module that combines both: The log in and the java script.

Does anyone of you have an idea, how I can do this!

Greetings
Sebastian

Comment: Have you looked into Selenium ?

Comment: Nope, not yet. Might that be a path that leads me there?

Comment: Yes, you can look into "Web Scraping using Selenium" you'll find a lot of tutorials.This might be the solution to your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I just started. I will see what my next issue will be :D Thank you very much!

Comment: If you figure out what is going in the JavaScript code without needing to execute it, your scraping code will be much faster and easy to execute. If you don't care about machine resources and prefer to save your time, there are several headless browsers solutions, even some SaaS. If you are not highly tied to python, you can take a look at Cypress, Puppeter, Zombie.js, [splash](https://www.scrapinghub.com/splash/), etc. Just search for `browser headless`.